# Rails change root-path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, alias

I have thingspeak server working on http://portail.lyc-st-exupery-bellegarde.ac-lyon.fr/srv3, witch is behind a proxy server.

how can i tell rails to add "srv3/" to all url ?

```
/srv3 should be the root.
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put all your routes in a **`scope` block**, like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "/srv3" do      
    root to: "root#index"
    ...
  end
end
```

Then all your routes will have the `/srv3` prefix:

```
$ rake routes
Prefix Verb URI Pattern     Controller#Action
root GET  /srv3(.:format) root#index
...
```

See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html) for more info.

Comment: it doesn not work
in routes.rb i have:
root :to => 'pages#home'

i see "Welcom aboard" page now !

Comment: Do you have the `'/srv3'` in your URL when viewing the page? I.e. do you view e.g. `http:/localhost:3000/srv3/` ?

Comment: http://localhost/ works fine, but not    http://localhost/srv3 (ruby is on port 80)

Comment: Strange, what does `rake routes` tell you?

Comment: root GET        /srv3(.:format)                                                  root#index
                     new_admin_user_session GET        /srv3/admin/login(.:format)                                      active_admin/devise/sessions#new
                         admin_user_session POST       /srv3/admin/login(.:format)


Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/channels/public"

[http://portail.lyc-st-exupery-bellegarde.ac-lyon.fr/srv3/channels/public]
Rails.root: /root/thingspeak

Answer (score -1):

I don't get much what you tryin to say, but what i could understand is that you want your root_path to be  http://portail.lyc-st-exupery-bellegarde.ac-lyon.fr/srv3 instead of  http://portail.lyc-st-exupery-bellegarde.ac-lyon.fr

if so then write something like this in your application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :check_url

def check_url
  if request.path_info == '/'
    redirect_to 'http://portail.lyc-st-exupery-bellegarde.ac-lyon.fr/srv3'
  end
end
```

or you can do something like this if you want to check authentication too

```
def check_url
  if request.path_info == '/' and current_user.present?
    redirect_to 'http://portail.lyc-st-exupery-bellegarde.ac-lyon.fr/srv3'
  end
end
```